# shared_ptr and unique_ptr constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers

When I use smart pointers, I always need to construct it with the factory functions, e.g. `std::make_shared<T>` and `std::make_unique<T>`, I don't use the constructor which takes a pointer because I try to avoid any usage/appearances of `new`. But my question is why C++ standard didn't include a constructor that takes argument list to forward to the type `T`? Like instead of `shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&...)`, can we have following:

```
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Args&&...) {...}
unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr(Args&&...) {...}
```

Comment: Might be tough (but not implausible) to get a non-opinion answer. The first thing that jumped into my head is what if `T` can be constructed from `T*`? Is the ambiguity of this case worth it? That could be a matter of opinion, unless someone can find notes  from the standards committee discussing that point.

Comment: Re "I try to avoid any usage/appearances of `new`", why? I know naked `new` calls are usually a bad idea, but not in all cases. Surely the keyword is okay if used within a smart pointer constructor?

Comment: One problem is that in that case you might expect no arguments to construct  an object with its default constructor, instead using `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically to avoid ambiguities and confusion.

Ambiguities arise because `std::shared_ptr` has over 10 constructor overloads and `std::unique_ptr` has also half dozen and lot of those are templates. So adding one that is meant to forward the arguments to managed object will either result with inability for compiler to choose what was meant or inability to reach some constructors of managed objects.

There is also likelihood of confusion of users even when ambiguity is somehow avoided. It is because `shared_ptr` constructors are meant for constructing `shared_ptr` objects while `make_shared` is meant for making objects managed by `shared_ptr`.

The idea of those factories is not to get rid of appearances of `new` in code. The `shared_ptr` that got its value from `make_shared` manages the resources differently than `shared_ptr` that got its value from one of constructors. Getting rid of `new` is only pleasant byproduct but we still keep needing those constructors (for example for to set deleter) so differentiating it in code simplifies reading it.

Comment: The shared_ptr that got its value from make_shared manages the resources differently than shared_ptr that got its value from one of constructors - can you explain what do you mean? how are they different?

Comment: The make_shared makes only one allocation for both control block and managed object. So such shared_ptr calls destructor of managed object when count of shared_ptr reaches zero but has to wait with deallocation of that whole memory until there are no weak_ptrs left. The shared_ptr that received pointer to manage allocates only control block and calls deleter (note not destructor) when count of shared_ptr reaches zero and deallocates that control block when count of weak_ptr reaches zero.

Comment: @fluter You might want to check out [cppreference's list of trade-offs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared#Notes).